# Edit: No implementation found for long org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromCaffe_0

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

I am using Android Studio to create a face recognition app using OpenCV library, While im seeing "NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.6, NDK version is UNKNOWN" Error When I run the app in the simulator trying to detect face in a picture I receive the following Error:

> "No implementation found for long org.opencv.dnn.Dnn.readNetFromCaffe_0(java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (tried Java_org_opencv_dnn_Dnn_readNetFromCaffe_10 and Java_org_opencv_dnn_Dnn_readNetFromCaffe_10__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2)"

Once I went to the Implementation of the `readNetFromCaffe_0` I realized that its using NDK native to operate, I suspect the problem could be NDK setup (although I think I have fully configured it)

and here is where the code throws a stop:

```
if (firsttimeFaces == false) {
    firsttimeFaces = true;
    String protoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dnns/deploy.prototxt";
    String caffeWeights = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dnns/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel";
    ##detector = Dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, caffeWeights);##
}
```

diving into `readNetFromCaffe` shows;

```
public static Net readNetFromCaffe(String prototxt, String caffeModel) {
    return new Net(readNetFromCaffe_0(prototxt, caffeModel));
}
```

and implementation of `readNetFromCaffe_0` shows;

```
private static native long readNetFromCaffe_0(String prototxt, String caffeModel);
```

With the help of Jordan I could realize that I have missed the

```
OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
```

hence the library was not even being initiated.

Right now, Im trying to capture the face and draw rectangle around it so that i know it detects the face using the code sequence below, although the code runs with no error I cant see the rectangle, code is as below;

```
if (checkedId == R.id.timein) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Recognition.this);
                    final EditText text = new EditText(Recognition.this);

                    builder.setTitle("Enter Your Staff ID: ").setMessage("").setView(text);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                            final String id = text.getText().toString();

                            Cursor cursor = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE staff_id=" + id);
                            if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);
                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                                if (firsttimeFaces == false) {
                                    firsttimeFaces = true;
                                    String protoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dnns/deploy.prototxt";
                                    String caffeWeights = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dnns/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel";

                                    detector = Dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, caffeWeights);

                                }

                                Mat loadedImage = new Mat();
                                Bitmap bmp32 = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                                Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, loadedImage);
                                Imgproc.cvtColor(loadedImage, loadedImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);


                                Mat imageblob = Dnn.blobFromImage(loadedImage, 1.0, new Size(300, 300), new Scalar(104.0, 177.0, 123.0), true, false, CvType.CV_32F);
                                detector.setInput(imageblob);
                                Mat detections = detector.forward();

                                int cols = loadedImage.cols();
                                int rows = loadedImage.cols();
                                double THRESHOLD = 0.55;

                                detections = detections.reshape(1, (int) detections.total() / 7);

                                Log.d("EXPERIMENT5:ROWS", detections.rows() + "");


                                for (int j = 0; j < detections.rows(); j++) {
                                    double confidence = detections.get(j, 2)[0];

                                    Log.d("EXPERIMENT6", j + " " + confidence + " " + THRESHOLD);
                                    if (confidence > THRESHOLD) {
                                        int left = (int) (detections.get(i, 3)[0] * cols);
                                        int top = (int) (detections.get(i, 4)[0] * rows);
                                        int right = (int) (detections.get(i, 5)[0] * cols);
                                        int bottom = (int) (detections.get(i, 6)[0] * rows);


                                        //rectangle draw

                                        if (left < 0) {
                                            left = 0;
                                        }
                                        if (top < 0) {
                                            top = 0;
                                        }
                                        if (right < 0) {
                                            right = 0;
                                        }
                                        if (bottom < 0) {
                                            bottom = 0;
                                        }

                                        int xLim = loadedImage.size(1);
                                        int yLim = loadedImage.size(0);

                                        if (left >= xLim) {
                                            left = xLim - 2;
                                        }
                                        if (right >= xLim) {
                                            right = xLim - 2;
                                        }
                                        if (top >= yLim) {
                                            top = yLim - 2;
                                        }
                                        if (bottom >= yLim) {
                                            bottom = yLim - 2;
                                        }

                                        Imgproc.rectangle(loadedImage, new Point(left, top), new Point(right, bottom), new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ID does not exist!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Regards,

Comment: Have you initialized the openCV library before using it in your activity?

Comment: Yeah, I have set the dependencies and imported OpenCV libraries, the main one for this error is org.opencv.dnn.DNN but yet im receiving the error

Comment: No I am asking about the calls in oncreate() method like OpenCVLoader.initDebug(); or a static call before oncreate() method which is static {System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");}

Comment: OMG! that was the issue, I was not initiating the library but the problem now is that it goes through the code with no jump outs but it wont create the rectangle around the face detected in the image, i dont even know if its detecting or not!
how can i present my code to you?

Comment: Edit your question and add your code and any additional details with an 'EDIT' title.